# WebKit CSS3 transition and SVG foreignObject with clipPath is overflowing

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have a svg object with an inline svg clipPath. Evereything seems to be halfway compatible to every modern browser. I just have an issue in WebKit browser like Safari or Google Chrome.

Inline SVG clipping path:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clippath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0 1, 0 0, 1 0, 1 1">
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

SVG Object for clipped content:

```
<svg>
    <foreignObject height="100%" width="100%" clip-path="url(#clippath)">
        <div ...>
        <div ...>
        <div ...>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

When i trigger a CSS3 transition with opacity on the inner elements of the svg object (slideshow) the clipPath gets ignored for the duration of transition.

The clipPath is defined on a "foreignObject". This object is the parent object of the clipped content. I have no idea how to describe it a better way.

Here is just my test HTML project: http://ogs.dev.ka-mediendesign.de/

Is there any solution to get the opacity animation working WITH the clipped path? The slide objects has to be defined as `position:static;`, because `position:absolute;` results in the same (clipPath gets ignored in WebKit browser).

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing a couple of slashes in the void elements.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a div that rotated as a cover?

```
<div class="clipath" style="
position: absolute;
background: #fff;
height: 200px;
bottom: -150px;
left: -100px;
width: calc(100% + 200px);
z-index: 1;
transform: rotate(-5deg);
"></div>
```

Add this inside your `parallelogram-box parallelogram-svg-path-topflat-true parallelogram-svg-path-bottomflat-false` div.

Also give `.headline-text-dce` `z-index:10;` Tested it works like a charm.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0m17kdrj/1/

Love the design btw.

Comment: Didn't understand exactly what you mean. With transform: rotate(-5deg); the image gets rotatet, right? What about the "flat top" of this object? Can you put that in a JsFiddle maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found another easy solution for me: Just do it vice versa: A white backgrounded object from the bottom overlapping the slideshow. Just as height as the overlapping part.